# GeoDataClient.getAutocompletePredictions - Canceling/Ignoring Previous Requests

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

***Android SDK***
https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete
(Look for Get place predictions programmatically)

GeoDataClient.getAutocompletePredictions() - I would like to ignore responses that are not the last request...
autoComplete typing for example:
'New'->'New Y'->'New Yo'

3 Responses - but I want to catch only the last one..
(Not Using RX)

```
// Submit the query to the autocomplete API and retrieve a PendingResult that will
   // contain the results when the query completes.
   Task<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse> results =
           geoDataClient.getAutocompletePredictions(constraint, bounds, typeFilter);
   results.addOnSuccessListener(autocompletePredictions -> {
       if (autoCompletePredictionsListener != null) {
           autoCompletePredictionsListener.onAutoCompleteSuccess(autocompletePredictions);
       }
//****Here I want to ignore(or cancel somewhere before) previous requests
       autocompletePredictions.release();
   });
```

***iOS SDK - Solved By Google Developers***
https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_autocomplete_fetcher

The delegate will only be called with prediction results if those predictions are for the text supplied in the most recent call to sourceTextHasChanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a similar need recently and this was what I did to achieve the desired result

```
// create a class-scope variable to track the most recent query
private String lastQuery;
private GeoDataClient geoDataClient;

// wrap the geoDataClient.getAutocompletePredictions in a class to associate the prediction results with the query that triggered the call
class AutocompletePredictor {
    String query;

    AutocompletePredictor(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    Task<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse> getPredictions(LatLngBounds bounds, AutocompleteFilter typeFilter) {
        return geoDataClient.getAutocompletePredictions(query, bounds, typeFilter);
    }
}

// modify your method that triggers the autocomplete filter
void filterAutocomplete(String constraint) {
    // update lastQuery every time this method is called
    lastQuery = constraint;

    // Submit the query to the autocomplete API and retrieve a PendingResult that will contain the results when the query completes.
    final AutocompletePredictor predictor = new AutocompletePredictor(constraint);
    Task<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse> results = predictor.getPredictions(bounds, typeFilter);

    results.addOnSuccessListener(autocompletePredictions -> {
        // checks if the query for this filter is same as the most recent query issued to this method
        if (autoCompletePredictionsListener != null && predictor.query.equals(lastQuery)) {
            autoCompletePredictionsListener.onAutoCompleteSuccess(autocompletePredictions);
        }

        autocompletePredictions.release();
    });
}
```

**Edit:** Delay calls when user is typing...
Instead of calling the autocomplete method each time the content of the EditText changes (which can be every time the user types a character), schedule the autocomplete call to wait for a period of time before actually executing. If the EditText content changes again before the waiting period elapses, cancel the previous schedule and re-schedule.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    int delayMilliseconds = 500;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        final String constraint = editable.toString();

        // remove all delayed/pending tasks set in the last 500 milliseconds
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

        // setup a new delayed task to execute after 500 milliseconds
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                filterAutocomplete(constraint);
            }
        }, delayMilliseconds);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank You! Simple And Good, What About delaying outgoing calls between characters typing?

Comment: Glad I could help . I've edited my answer with a way to delay outgoing calls when user is typing. You can increase or reduce the value of the delayMilliseconds variable as needed.

Answer (score 1):

It is not good, because all you do is filter result for displaying, but actually, all geoDataClient tasks are completed asynchronously eventually, drastically decreasing usage quota. Handler solves this issue partially.

So we need some other way to cancel geoDataClient.getAutocompletePrediction task in a way regular API call can do.